# Expand only the cell that has been tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have some code in my app that expands a cell when it is tapped. The problem is that I haven't figured out how to only expand the cell that has been tapped. At the moment my code just expands all of the cells.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row {
        if cellTapped == false {
            cellTapped = true
            return 141
        } else {
            cellTapped = false
            return 70
        }
    }
    return 70
}
```

What do I need to do to only expand the cell that has been tapped?

Comment: Do you want cell expansion to toggle on and off such that you can have multiple expanded cells or do you want the expansion of a new cell to collapse the previously expanded cell?

Comment: Your code works ok for me. I don't see multiple cells being expanded.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm trying to achieve the later.

Comment: I don't know why you are toggling `cellTapped`. You should simply return 141 if the row valus are equal, otherwise return 70.

Comment: @rdelmar Ah. What seems to be happening is that if the bottom cell is tapped, then the blank cells all expand to the same size. Is this how it should function? I would rather they just stay at height 70.

Comment: That's normal. You can get rid of those extra blank rows by adding a footer view (self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()). I don't know how to make them stay at 70 if you still want to see those blank rows.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Also, without opening a new question I was wondering how I create the objects that will be in the expanded part of the cell? If I just create them in the prototype cell then they overlap into the other cells.

Comment: @Paulw11 If I understand what you are suggesting, the issue with that is the fact that the user cannot tap the cell to reduce the size of it, they can only tap another cell to expand it. Are you suggesting to check if `indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row` and if so return 141, otherwise return 68?

Comment: I was just trying to clarify whether keeping a single "expanded cell" index was sufficient or whether you needed to store the expanded state for multiple cells, but yes, if you only want to expand the selected cell, that should be all the logic you need

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following worked for me.  The cells are 70 high and expand when tapped :

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var cellTapped:Bool = true
    var currentRow = 0;
```

Then I slightly modified the following two methods:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == currentRow {
        if cellTapped == false {
            cellTapped = true
            return 141
        } else {
            cellTapped = false
            return 70
        }
    }
    return 70
}
```

Comment: Great answer. When the view loads, my first row is expanded. Any ideas?

Comment: Change var currentRow = 0 to var currentRow = -1