# Expand the only tapped cell and collapse other cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am doing expand/collapse when tapped on tableview cell, but I have to close all other cells except the tapped one. Tried this solution [Expand only the cell that has been tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318209/expand-only-the-cell-that-has-been-tapped/26436537) this solution is not working for me.

below code which I have written for expand/collapse

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datasource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ExpandingTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ExpandingTableViewCell
        cell.set(content: datasource[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let content = datasource[indexPath.row]
        content.expanded = !content.expanded
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collapse all cells and change the current clicked one state , then reload all the table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let current =  datasource[indexPath.row].expanded
    datasource.forEach {  $0.expanded = false }
    let content = datasource[indexPath.row]
    content.expanded = !current 
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```